# Android gradle test framework: single class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Is it possible to run a single test class using the new Android gradle build framework?

I have a test package that has multiple test classes (All of them are InstrumentationTestCase classes).  I've been able to setup my build.gradle file to run the test package

```
defaultConfig{
    testPackageName "com.company.product.tests"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
}
```

But is there a way to test only one test case in that package? Otherwise I'll be using the age old `adb shell am instrument -w .......`

P.S. I don't have time right now to switch to Roboelectric, but I do see that its pretty much the defacto framework nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner` no, this is not possible. You do, however, have options:

### Custom Test Runner

1. Extend `android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`
2. Add a `buildConfigField 'String', 'TEST_NAME', '${testName}'`, where `testName` is `'"${project.properties.get("test")}"'` if set, otherwise null
3. In your runner, only run tests that match BuildConfig.TEST_NAME (if null, run all tests)
4. Replace the `testInstrumentationRunner` with your custom runner
5. Run tests with `./gradlew connectedCheck -Ptest=com.example.Test.testSomething`

### Use Spoon

[Spoon](https://github.com/square/spoon) is an excellent test runner extension that, among other things (like beautiful multi-device test reports), lets you run individual tests. Since you're using gradle, I recommend the [Spoon Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin), which has an example of exactly what you want to do in its README.

### Update: Run Individual Unit Tests with Android Gradle Plugin

With the addition of unit testing support, Android now supports running individul unit tests.

> This is just an anchor task, actual test tasks are called `testDebug` and `testReleas`e etc. If you want to run only some tests, using the `gradle --tests` flag, you can do it by running `./gradlew testDebug --tests='*.MyTestClass'`.

[Source](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support)

**Edit**: I should also add that Spoon is a drop-in replacement for running tests. You will not have to modify anything but a few lines in your build script to use it.

Answer (score 3):

As answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32603798 there is now
`android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class`