# Gradle: How to run instrumentation test for class

Tags: android, testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I'm running instrumentation test in Android Studio with Run Configuration defined as below (don't mind warning):
[image]

So this is invoking test suit for a specific class. How can I achieve this with command line, I guess using ./gradlew command ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As stated in the [AndroidTestingBlueprint](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint) you can use the `android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class` property:

```
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.android.testing.blueprint.ui.espresso.EspressoTest
```

Comment: how to run it for a particular method?

Comment: `./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -P android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.android.testing.blueprint.ui.espresso.EspressoTest#someMethodToTest`

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#RunTestsDevice):

> When you run tests from the command-line with Android Debug Bridge
>   (adb), you get more options for choosing the tests to run than with
>   any other method. You can select individual test methods, filter tests
>   according to their annotation, or specify testing options. Since the
>   test run is controlled entirely from a command-line, you can customize
>   your testing with shell scripts in various ways.

To run instrumentation tests with adb for a particular class do:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class 'com.myapp.MyActivityTest' com.myapp.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Note that if you've defined a custom `testInstrumentationRunner` on your `app/build.gradle` file then you need to replace `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` with your own, like this:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e class 'com.myapp.MyActivityTest' com.myapp.test/com.myapp.MyCustomTestRunner
```

**Tip:** If you get an error because the command isn't right, know that you can simply get the right command by running the tests from within Android Studio. You'll see the command on the Run window output.

---

These 2 documentation pages contain execution options:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner#typical-usage

https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#AMSyntax