# How to create a gradle task that runs specific espresso test

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32603798/190148) describes a way to run a specific espresso test:

```
./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.my.tests.MyTest
```

But I would like to create a gradle task to run it like this:

```
./gradlew app:runMyTest
```

But when I try to define `runMyTest` task:

```
task runMyTest {
    finalizedBy connectedDAT

    project.extensions.add("android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class", "com.my.tests.MyTest")
}
```

and run it, all my tests run, not only the specified one.

Comment: connectedDAT == connectedAndroidTest ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
  filter {
      //specific test method
      includeTestsMatching "com.yourpackage.YourTest"
  }
}
```

or check the sample code below and work something out,

```
sourceSets {

  integration {
    java.srcDir 'src/test/integration/java'
    resources.srcDir 'src/test/resources'
    compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
    runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
  }

}

configurations {
  integrationCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
  integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integration(type: Test, description: 'Runs the integration tests.', group: 'Verification') {
  testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
  classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
}
```